# How do I check if the uploaded file has the right format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, format, binaryreader

I work with c# and asp.net

I created a webpage with a web form where you enter your information in order to submit it. There is also a file upload on my page: `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadPassfoto" runat="server"/>` In my c# code behind i coded a IF-Loop which checks if something got uploaded. Like this:

```
if (FileUploadPassfoto.HasFile == true)
{
      HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadPassfoto.PostedFile;
      using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
      {
          lehrling.passfoto = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
      }
      LabelPassfotoError.Visible = false;
}
else
{
     LabelPassfotoError.Visible = true;
     LabelError.Visible = true;
}
```

What it does is: As i said it checks if something got uploaded. If nothing got uploaded a ErrorLabel will be shown so the user knows he forgot to upload.

What i want to check too, is if the uploaded file is a image. To be more clear i only want to accept .jpg/.bmp and .gif. If a wrong format gets uploaded i want to display my ErrorLabel as well.

I dont really know how i should do this, can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, i know it is but i just wanted a anwer where my id's and methods..... etc. are shown so its easier for me... cause im new in this business xD i'll delete it. Thanks for you help @David

Comment: i just looked at the page you linked to me. i have no idea how i should implement this in my case! i'm sorry but i wont delete my question.... @David

Comment: What specifically is unclear?  The more I look at that other answer, the more identical it seems to this question.  Did you try to implement that function?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @David how do i write this in a if-loop i tried this: if(myupload.postedfile.width......) i am trying to check if the image has the right resolution can you help me

Comment: For starters, an `if` isn't a "loop".  And the function in the answer returns a `bool`, so you'd literally just check that function.  `if (YourFunction(file))`  Within that function you would check anything you need to check.  The linked answer checks the MIME type, the file extension, if it can convert to a `Bitmap`, etc.  Add any other checks you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string strFileWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFileName);
        string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);
        if (strExtension == ".jpg" || strExtension == ".bmp" || strExtension == ".gif")
        {
            string strImageFolder = "~/YourFilePath/";
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(strImageFolder)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(strImageFolder));
            string _strPath = Server.MapPath(strImageFolder) + strFileName;
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(_strPath);
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded.";
        }
        else
            Label1.Text = "Upload status: only .jpg,.bmp and .gif file are allowed!";
    }
```

Hope Its Help You much more....

Comment: If you do this you should use `string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName.ToLower());` If someone uploads an image with a uppercase extension your validation will fail.

Comment: yes right, thanks :)..

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of the link that David has posted in the comments.

```
HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadPassfoto.PostedFile;
if (file.ContentType == "image/x-png" || file.ContentType == "image/pjpeg" || file.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || file.ContentType == "image/bmp" || file.ContentType == "image/png" || file.ContentType == "image/gif")
{
    // it is an image
}
```

Comment: in which directory is .contenttype in?

Comment: What do you mean by directory? ContentType is a property of the HttpPostedFile class.